# HTML CSS Input exceeds width

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I cannot seem to find a solution to my issue, which is why I'm here.

I cannot, for the life of me, make the input remain within its parent div.
This following code is an isolated small-scale replication of the issue, just to make sure there's nothing else affecting it.

If you use the following code, you'll see that the inputs side by side, somehow are wider than their owner.

```css
.main-container
{
    width: 30%;
    background-color: grey;
    height: 50px;
    display: flex;
}

.inner-container
{
    width: 100%;
}

input
{
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>

<div class="main-container">
    <div class="inner-container">
        <input>
    </div>
    <div class="inner-container">
        <input>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

If anyone could please point to my mistake, I'd be extremely happy.

Thank you all in advance,
Matt

Comment: Please don't use `* { box-sizing: border-box; }`. Instead use the inheritance-based approach I've shown in my answer. For the reasons read https://www.paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/ and especially https://css-tricks.com/inheriting-box-sizing-probably-slightly-better-best-practice/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that you are using the *default [box model](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing)*, in which `padding` and `border` are ***added*** to `width` (thus `width` in this model actually means *content width*).

`input` elements by default have some user agent (browser) styles applied to them, part of which are `padding` and `border`. As you have defined `width: 100%` these get added to those `100%` and this results in an element, that visually requires more space than is available.

To fix it (and further problems of this sort, usually resulting from working with percentages), switch your page to the more easy-to-handle `border-box` model (in which `width` actually means *visual width*) using the following CSS:

```css
:root { box-sizing: border-box; }
*, *::before, *::after, *::marker { box-sizing: inherit; }
```

Here you can see the user agent styles applied by Chrome:

[image]

Comment: Very detailed response. Thank you very much. Actually trying to make me understand instead of giving me a straight answer is the best answer I could've hoped for.

Answer (score 0):

Add `box-sizing: border-box;`

```css
   *{box-sizing: border-box;}
.main-container
{
    width: 30%;
    background-color: grey;
    height: 50px;
    display: flex;
}

.inner-container
{
    width: 100%;
}

input
{
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>

<div class="main-container">
    <div class="inner-container">
        <input>
    </div>
    <div class="inner-container">
        <input>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This, while fixing the issue, is not best practice approach. @OP Please don't use this solution. See here why: https://www.paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/ and especially https://css-tricks.com/inheriting-box-sizing-probably-slightly-better-best-practice/

Comment: Your question asks for an explanation of *why* what you did didn't work out the way you expected it to work. That answer also lacks this explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I just added `box-sizing: border-box;` to the input and it worked.

```
input
{
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The main issue in this snippet can be solved by applying `box-sizing: border-box;` to the `input` in order to include border and padding in the 100% width.

Apart from that, the `width: 100%` for `.inner-container` isn't quite correct here: It should be 50%. However, it actually is ignored in this case since the parent element is a flex container, so the children's widths are set automatically by default.

```css
.main-container {
  width: 30%;
  background-color: grey;
  height: 50px;
  display: flex;
}

.inner-container {
  width: 50%;
}

input {
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Page Title</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="main-container">
    <div class="inner-container">
      <input>
    </div>
    <div class="inner-container">
      <input>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.main-container
{
    width: 50%;
    background-color: grey;
    height: 50px;
    display: flex;
}

.inner-container
{
    width: 95%;
}

input
{
    width: 95%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>

<div class="main-container">
    <div class="inner-container">
        <input>
    </div>
    <div class="inner-container">
        <input>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: it would be very useful if you also enter the reason for the changes and not just the code.